# Sorting a dataframe by userId and count both in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to sort a particular dataframe by 2 columns. My dataframe has been grouped by user_id and track_id for which I have the counts. Now for each user_id I would like to sort it by the count.

[image: Here is the dataframe]

I want to sort this data frame by user_id and count.

For example,

```
    user_id track_id    counts
0   2115525 128           2
1   2115525 176           4
2   2115525 178           4
3   2115525 271           7
4   2115525 287          22
```

should become

```
    user_id track_id    counts
0   2115525 287          22
1   2115525 271          7
2   2115525 178          4
3   2115525 176          4
4   2115525 128          2
```

Comment: `sort_values` seems like the solution for this

Answer (score 3):

```
df.sort_values(by=['user_id', 'counts'], ascending=False, inplace=True)
```

This will sort by user_id and counts descending. For further documentation, see https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html